# Why am I launching the tests incorrectly?

Tags: java, junit, hamcrest

Basically I am building a project for an assignment that has bunch of tests that needs to pass using Junit. But I seem to be trying to run it incorrectly and I don't know how or why

Basically i have directory like this

> [project]
>   Test.java
>   junit-4.12.jar
>   hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
>   src/cards/bunch of files
>   src/boards/bunch of files

So first thing I did is compile the project using `javac Test.java` after few small fixes it compiled, so next thing I wanted to do is launch the actual tests.

So I launched it with `java -cp ./junit-4.12.jar:./hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. Test.java`

I get the following error

> Error: Could not find or load main class Test.java

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

**EDIT:** As you can see compilation went through, i'm referencing at least presumably correctly to JUnit. Here's how's my directory structured

[image: My directory].

And how's my test file looking

[image]

Comment: maybe you should compile first your `Test.java` file

Comment: What IDE are you using?

Comment: @freedev not one in particular, just linux command line, though i have netbeans installed on the computer, i just dont like it too much.

Comment: Have you compiled the `Test.java` file?

Comment: @freedev well keep in mind im beginner to java, but if I understood properly, `javac Test.java` should do the trick? It generated Test.class in my directory - or does that not count as compiling?

Comment: Right. it is correct. Now run `java` the command in the directory where is the `Test.class` file. I suggest to have a look at this [tutorial on JavaUnitTesting](https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaUnitTesting.html)

Comment: Have your `Test` class a package?

Comment: I've corrected my post

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should compile first your `Test.java` file.

Then specify the correct packages if there is one

```
java -cp ./junit-4.12.jar:./hamcrest-core-1.3.jar:. src.Test
```

Take a look at where is your `Test.class` file

Here you'll find a complete example that explains how to run your tests from command line.

https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JavaUnitTesting.html